# Are trivial user interface concepts patentable and can they be used?

Tags: software, patents

A few years ago there were some news headlines about that Microsoft is getting royalty fee from Android phones manufactures, because of some Android user interface basic concepts, that were patented by Microsoft. Unfortunately, none of them explain exactly which specific UI elements or concepts was the reason:

[Why Microsoft Makes $5 to $15 From Every Android Device Sold](https://www.howtogeek.com/183766/why-microsoft-makes-5-to-15-from-every-android-device-sold/)

Currently, I am developing my own UI library *for Windows*. My  library provides mechanisms for Windows-developers to create beautiful GUI programs, and I want to sell it in the future. The main advantage of my UI library is that it does not use any of the standard Windows controls, because I am rewriting it on my own.

Although most of UI controls are initially "clean" and need to be set up, customized, some controls already have predefined behavior and the way it displayed, for example - text input field. When developer creates it, it already has an ability to select text via mouse, move caret using keyboard.

The fact that is worrying me, is that logic, that experience exists in existing controls. Stuff like caret, selecting text using a mouse, scrollbars, etc. But in the other hand I am going to distribute it only for Windows.

Can those be patented by Microsoft or someone else? Can Microsoft suing me, if I will sell GUI library that imitating their patented conceptions only for Windows platform?

**Update**

I am asking specifically about text selection using mouse.

Comment: "*Can the owner go to court, saying I stole his ideas[...]?*" Sure, multiple patents have been granted, for example, on scroll bars. *Is it likely that they sue you?* Depends on how successful your library is. *Is it likely that they win?* Depends on the details (how does your UI control look exactly, what patents are claimed to be infringed, how non-obvious are those patents actually, etc.). *Will you be able to financially survive a legal battle against one of the giants, even if you win in the end?* Only you can answer that...

Comment: @Heinzi, my GUI library provides developer an ability to create their own controls or other ui elements from the basic kit, like css. I rather asking about experience or functionality - for example selecting text using mouse - can it be patented? I rewrite this functionality by myself it experiences almost the same, but for example it does not select a single word in text by double clicking it as existing input fields do

Comment: Yes, there are also patents on selecting text with a mouse (just search Google for `patent text selection mouse`).

Comment: `The main advantage of my UI library is that it does not use any of the standard Windows controls, because I am rewriting it on my own.`  This is actually a **disadvantage**.  For instance, this is likely to prevent people from using screen readers with your software, since they won't know about it (unless you put in extra work to wire that up).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, perhaps You didn't understand what did I mean. My gui library dedicated to Windows developers, so they can use it build their Windows program with pretty interfaces. In particularly, my library gives an ability to create the text input field, that behaves almost the same the field You used to write Your comment. The key moment is that I rewrite all of logics on my own

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to be referring to the lawsuit between Apple and MS, claiming that the Windows UI copied the Mac. This was decades before smart phones. It's the reason why the Windows trash bin looks different from the Mac's.

Comment: @Barmar I removed that, but no - I read exactly about Xerox, try to Google

Comment: @Barmar *Gates made a rather famous statement:

I think it’s more like we both had this rich neighbor named Xerox and I broke into his house to steal the TV set and found out that you had already stolen it* - https://medium.com/bc-digest/the-xerox-thieves-steve-jobs-bill-gates-6e1b36fc1ec4 or https://www.quora.com/Did-Bill-Gates-get-Windows-from-Xerox

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd If you keep reading, the actual story is that MS got it from Mac, not from Xerox.

Comment: @Barmar, yeah, but I focused exactly on Xerox, it's Alto pc was the first. And nowadays stuff like desktop, icons are trivial, but they was not all the time - they was originally invented by someone, and another "someone" patented it

Answer (score 6):

Trivial is hard to judge after the fact due to hindsight bias. Once you know the answer to a riddle it seems obvious but you couldn’t figure it out without already knowing it.

The criteria for get a patent in the US does not include the word or concept “trivial”. It does include non-obviousness. To reduce hindsight bias an examiner needs to follow a process of identifying all sub- components of an invention in the prior art and then making a good argument as to how someone of ordinary skill in the field would be motivated to put them together.

Also there is no measure of improvement over past technology required for a patent. A trivial  improvement in cost or performance is fine. Actually no objective improvement is required at all. An existing solution might work as well or better than your invention. That means probably no one will buy it but if it is novel and not obvious one can get a patent.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, but I rather asked not about patenting the solution I write, but just about ability to sell it legally, so non of the companies could suing me

Comment: Obviously if X holds a patent and licenses it for a million dollar, and you have a different patent that allows me to achieve my goals in a different way, and you license it for half the amount, I’d be very interested.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don’t have a patent and I am not going to have it

Comment: Stdug: You need to understand both sides. Like you need to know how cars work to understand how to cross a road safely as a pedestrian. And note that the universe doesn’t revolve around you.

Comment: @gnasher729, okay, I just pointed, that I am not going to patent something

Comment: I was explaining the criteria for getting a patent so you could better understand that others may have patents on something that might seem trivial. I understand you are worried about infringement not about getting patents. I changed “you can” to “one can”.

Comment: I think need to pay some service that will find out whether technology I want to use is patented. Maybe You know some of them, maybe in US?

Comment: Google patent searcher. Many are near the patent office. If you are serious you would get a “freedom to operate” search.

Answer (score 4):

A concept that is "trivial" is almost always one that would be obvious to persons trained in the relevant art (in this case the relevant kind of coding) and thus would not be patentable. *See* 35 U.S.C. § 103(a) which states:

> A patent for a claimed invention may not be obtained, notwithstanding
> that the claimed invention is not identically disclosed as set forth
> in section 102, if the differences between the claimed invention and
> the prior art are such that the claimed invention as a whole would
> have been obvious before the effective filing date of the claimed
> invention to a person having ordinary skill in the art to which the
> claimed invention pertains. Patentability shall not be negated by the
> manner in which the invention was made.

Comment: The problem is that the things that are trivial are trivial only for thirty years, from the time it was invented. Before, that trivial things just didn't exist

Comment: Of course trivial things existed. Many were both trivial and obvious, therefore widely used and unpatrntable. Others were trivial, not obvious, but openly used by someone and therefore unpatentable.